# Electron apps i.e. mongotron not getting started

Tags: node.js, electron

I was trying to start mongotron from its source by running below command from root , src, and or src/browser

```
electron .
```

However, it did not produce anything (no window nor error).

When I try to run this

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/electron-prebuilt/dist/Electron.app/Contents/MacOS/Electron
```

it returns me below error

> p/Contents/MacOS/Electron ; exit;ectron-prebuilt/dist/Electron.ap 
>   Illegal instruction: 4 logout

[Process completed]

Any suggestion how to troubleshoot? Thanks!

Comment: Are the instructions in the [Quick Start](https://github.com/officert/mongotron#quick-start) not working for you?

Comment: It did not help. I run gulp run which supposed to start the app. It returns me a whole bunch of text (last few lines are copied below) without error, but that's it...   >> [08:35:54] gulp-symlink:/Users/beng/git/mongotron/tests symlinked to ./node_modules/tests
[08:35:54] gulp-symlink:/Users/beng/git/mongotron/package.json symlinked to ./node_modules/package.json
[08:35:54] Finished 'dev-sym-links' after 202 m